# Get All results without filters in Cisco AXL CUCM

Tags: cucm, cisco-axl

I can't get the entire results of particular function like listPhone or getConferenceBridge, as it requires to provide particular search through searchCriteria.

Could anyone propose a solution for that except directly querying the database?

```
service.listPhone() ## gives error, because it's missing the filters.
```

[image: Attached screenshot of the documentation of getPhone]

Schema ref : [Schema Ref documentation](https://developer.cisco.com/docs/axl-schema-reference/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values for the search criteria elements are evaluated as SQL LIKE statements, meaning you can use wildcards, for example '%' which means 'match anything':

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/11.5">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:listPhone>
         <searchCriteria>
            <name>%</name>
         </searchCriteria>
         <returnedTags>
            <name/>
            <description/>
            <product/>
            <model/>
         </returnedTags>
      </ns:listPhone>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

CUCM uses an Informix DB under the covers: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1388.htm

Note, you will want to take care when executing a 'retrieve all' request like this, as you could return huge data sets on large clusters.  AXL data set size throttling may kick in: https://developer.cisco.com/docs/axl/#!axl-developer-guide/data-throttling-and-performance